# How can I disable querystring parameter submission in the GetListAsync() Controller?

Tags: abp

How can I disable querystring parameter submission in the GetListAsync() Controller?
I would like to use modelbinding instead of querystring.

Comment: Is it your controller or the controller in the module?

Comment: In the controller auto-generated by apb

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: I don't think you can change the signature of a Controller in the framework. maybe you can write your own Controller and call it.